# UDP hole punching in python, works locally but not through AWS

Tags: python, udp, hole-punching

I'm trying to implement UDP hole punching so that I can connect 2 clients together that are not in the same network without the need to portforward. I'm using the top answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53479668/how-to-make-2-clients-connect-each-other-directly-after-having-both-connected-a) as my basis and it works if I run the clients and the server on my local machine (both clients get the "hello" response).

Now I've made an AWS instance that is running the server and opened the ports on it so my clients can connect, however when they've received the ip + port for each other they seem to not reach (they get the response "peer: x.x.x.x yyyy", but not the "hello" response). What am I missing in order to make them capable of communicating? even if both clients are on the same machine it still doesn't work, it only gives the correct response when using the local host (127.0.0.1) for both the client and the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "NAT" (Network Address Translation) translates private addresses to a public one when a packet is routed from the internal to the external interface and vice versa in order to allow bi-directional communication.

First a short summary how it works when both clients are behind its own NAT:

- step 1: using a common server both clients must exchange their addresses and agree on port numbers for their future UDP communication: (IP1, port1) <---> (IP2, port2). Note that both IP addresses are the public addresses of the corresponding NAT routers.
- step 2: they both must send a packet to the other side before the channel is usable, the purpose is to create a NAT table entry in each NAT router.
- step 3: peers can now exchange UDP packets. Note that each packet goes through both NAT routers.

Now assume clients A and B are on the same private network behind the same NAT and the common server is elsewhere. In this case:

- step 1: no problem here, but IP1 == IP2 == IP of the public interface of the local NAT router
- step 2: a packet to the other side is a packet addressed to the local NAT router. It will not be forwarded to router's external interface, i.e no NAT necessary, no entry created. The router problably answers with ICMP port unreachable.
- step 3: no chance, as you see

Comment: Thank you very much for this response, I tried the same code on machines in different networks and it appears to work. Are there more failure cases I should be aware of? is it possible that there are cases where IP1 != IP2 but they are still behind the same NAT?

Comment: I do not know detail about all sceniarios, but I think there could be several other possible obstacles. For example if your ISP has multiple NATs and by chance it uses one for connecting to the server and another for connecting to the other peer. But if all machines are under your control, why don't you debug and analyze the issue? Print what is sent/received and compare it with the expected behavior. Use a tool like tcpdump or wireshark if necessary.